# Beginner Scoring program button development in Java

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm trying to add a "green team" to an example scoring GUI I found online. For some reason, the code compiles, but it runs with only the original two teams. I've tried playing around with the sizes/locations somewhat clumsily, and since no change was observed with these modications (NO change at ALL), I admit that I must be missing some necessary property or something. Any help? Here's the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.Color;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


public class ButtonDemo_Extended3 implements  ActionListener{



    // Definition of global values and items that are part of the GUI.

    int redScoreAmount = 0;

    int blueScoreAmount = 0;
    int greenScoreAmount = 0;



    JPanel titlePanel, scorePanel, buttonPanel;

    JLabel redLabel, blueLabel,greenLabel, redScore, blueScore, greenScore;

    JButton redButton, blueButton, greenButton,resetButton;



    public JPanel createContentPane (){



        // We create a bottom JPanel to place everything on.

        JPanel totalGUI = new JPanel();

        totalGUI.setLayout(null);



        // Creation of a Panel to contain the title labels

        titlePanel = new JPanel();

        titlePanel.setLayout(null);

        titlePanel.setLocation(0, 0);

        titlePanel.setSize(500, 500);

        totalGUI.add(titlePanel);



        redLabel = new JLabel("Red Team");

        redLabel.setLocation(300, 0);

        redLabel.setSize(100, 30);

        redLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(0);

        redLabel.setForeground(Color.red);

        titlePanel.add(redLabel);



        blueLabel = new JLabel("Blue Team");

        blueLabel.setLocation(900, 0);

        blueLabel.setSize(100, 30);

        blueLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(0);

        blueLabel.setForeground(Color.blue);

        titlePanel.add(blueLabel);

    greenLabel = new JLabel("Green Team");

        greenLabel.setLocation(600, 0);

        greenLabel.setSize(100, 30);

        greenLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(0);

        greenLabel.setForeground(Color.green);

        titlePanel.add(greenLabel);



        // Creation of a Panel to contain the score labels.

        scorePanel = new JPanel();

        scorePanel.setLayout(null);

        scorePanel.setLocation(10, 40);

        scorePanel.setSize(500, 30);

        totalGUI.add(scorePanel);



        redScore = new JLabel(""+redScoreAmount);

        redScore.setLocation(0, 0);

        redScore.setSize(40, 30);

        redScore.setHorizontalAlignment(0);

        scorePanel.add(redScore);

    greenScore = new JLabel(""+greenScoreAmount);

        greenScore.setLocation(60, 0);

        greenScore.setSize(40, 30);

        greenScore.setHorizontalAlignment(0);

        scorePanel.add(greenScore);



        blueScore = new JLabel(""+blueScoreAmount);

        blueScore.setLocation(130, 0);

        blueScore.setSize(40, 30);

        blueScore.setHorizontalAlignment(0);

        scorePanel.add(blueScore);



        // Creation of a Panel to contain all the JButtons.

        buttonPanel = new JPanel();

        buttonPanel.setLayout(null);

        buttonPanel.setLocation(10, 80);

        buttonPanel.setSize(2600, 70);

        totalGUI.add(buttonPanel);



        // We create a button and manipulate it using the syntax we have

        // used before. Now each button has an ActionListener which posts 

        // its action out when the button is pressed.

        redButton = new JButton("Red Score!");

        redButton.setLocation(0, 0);

        redButton.setSize(30, 30);

        redButton.addActionListener(this);

        buttonPanel.add(redButton);



        blueButton = new JButton("Blue Score!");

        blueButton.setLocation(150, 0);

        blueButton.setSize(30, 30);

        blueButton.addActionListener(this);

        buttonPanel.add(blueButton);

    greenButton = new JButton("Green Score!");

        greenButton.setLocation(250, 0);

        greenButton.setSize(30, 30);

        greenButton.addActionListener(this);

        buttonPanel.add(greenButton);



        resetButton = new JButton("Reset Score");

        resetButton.setLocation(0, 100);

        resetButton.setSize(50, 30);

        resetButton.addActionListener(this);

        buttonPanel.add(resetButton);



        totalGUI.setOpaque(true);

        return totalGUI;

    }



    // This is the new ActionPerformed Method.

    // It catches any events with an ActionListener attached.

    // Using an if statement, we can determine which button was pressed

    // and change the appropriate values in our GUI.

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getSource() == redButton)

        {

            redScoreAmount = redScoreAmount + 1;

            redScore.setText(""+redScoreAmount);

        }

        else if(e.getSource() == blueButton)

        {

            blueScoreAmount = blueScoreAmount + 1;

            blueScore.setText(""+blueScoreAmount);

        }
    else if(e.getSource() == greenButton)

        {

            greenScoreAmount = greenScoreAmount + 1;

            greenScore.setText(""+greenScoreAmount);

        }

        else if(e.getSource() == resetButton)

        {

            redScoreAmount = 0;

            blueScoreAmount = 0;
        greenScoreAmount = 0;

            redScore.setText(""+redScoreAmount);

            blueScore.setText(""+blueScoreAmount);
        greenScore.setText(""+greenScoreAmount);

        }

    }



    private static void createAndShowGUI() {



        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("[=] JButton Scores! [=]");



        //Create and set up the content pane.

        ButtonDemo_Extended demo = new ButtonDemo_Extended();

        frame.setContentPane(demo.createContentPane());



        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setSize(1024, 768);

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:

        //creating and showing this application's GUI.

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                createAndShowGUI();

            }

        });

    }

}
```

Comment: The null layouts are probably part of the problem, at least...

Answer (score 1):

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


public class ButtonDemo_Extended3 implements  ActionListener{



// Definition of global values and items that are part of the GUI.

int redScoreAmount = 0;

int blueScoreAmount = 0;
int greenScoreAmount = 0;



JPanel titlePanel, scorePanel, buttonPanel;

JLabel redLabel, blueLabel,greenLabel, redScore, blueScore, greenScore;

JButton redButton, blueButton, greenButton,resetButton;



public JPanel createContentPane (){



    // We create a bottom JPanel to place everything on.

    JPanel totalGUI = new JPanel();

    totalGUI.setLayout(null);



    // Creation of a Panel to contain the title labels

    titlePanel = new JPanel();

    titlePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    titlePanel.setLocation(0, 0);

    titlePanel.setSize(500, 500);





    redLabel = new JLabel("Red Team");

    redLabel.setLocation(300, 0);

    redLabel.setSize(100, 30);

    redLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(0);

    redLabel.setForeground(Color.red);

    titlePanel.add(redLabel, 0 );



    blueLabel = new JLabel("Blue Team");

    blueLabel.setLocation(900, 0);

    blueLabel.setSize(100, 30);

    blueLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(0);

    blueLabel.setForeground(Color.blue);

    titlePanel.add(blueLabel, 1);

greenLabel = new JLabel("Green Team");

    greenLabel.setLocation(600, 0);

    greenLabel.setSize(100, 30);

    greenLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(0);

    greenLabel.setForeground(Color.green);

    titlePanel.add(greenLabel);



    // Creation of a Panel to contain the score labels.

    scorePanel = new JPanel();

    scorePanel.setLayout(null);

    scorePanel.setLocation(10, 40);

    scorePanel.setSize(500, 30);





    redScore = new JLabel(""+redScoreAmount);

    redScore.setLocation(0, 0);

    redScore.setSize(40, 30);

    redScore.setHorizontalAlignment(0);

    scorePanel.add(redScore);

greenScore = new JLabel(""+greenScoreAmount);

    greenScore.setLocation(60, 0);

    greenScore.setSize(40, 30);

    greenScore.setHorizontalAlignment(0);

    scorePanel.add(greenScore);



    blueScore = new JLabel(""+blueScoreAmount);

    blueScore.setLocation(130, 0);

    blueScore.setSize(40, 30);

    blueScore.setHorizontalAlignment(0);

    scorePanel.add(blueScore);



    // Creation of a Panel to contain all the JButtons.

    buttonPanel = new JPanel();

    buttonPanel.setLayout(null);

    buttonPanel.setLocation(10, 80);

    buttonPanel.setSize(2600, 70);





    // We create a button and manipulate it using the syntax we have

    // used before. Now each button has an ActionListener which posts 

    // its action out when the button is pressed.

    redButton = new JButton("Red Score!");

    redButton.setLocation(0, 0);

    redButton.setSize(30, 30);

    redButton.addActionListener(this);

    buttonPanel.add(redButton);



    blueButton = new JButton("Blue Score!");

    blueButton.setLocation(150, 0);

    blueButton.setSize(30, 30);

    blueButton.addActionListener(this);

    buttonPanel.add(blueButton);

greenButton = new JButton("Green Score!");

    greenButton.setLocation(250, 0);

    greenButton.setSize(30, 30);

    greenButton.addActionListener(this);

    buttonPanel.add(greenButton);



    resetButton = new JButton("Reset Score");

    resetButton.setLocation(0, 100);

    resetButton.setSize(50, 30);

    resetButton.addActionListener(this);

    buttonPanel.add(resetButton);



    totalGUI.setOpaque(true);

    totalGUI.add(buttonPanel);
    totalGUI.add(scorePanel);
    totalGUI.add(titlePanel);

    return totalGUI;

}



// This is the new ActionPerformed Method.

// It catches any events with an ActionListener attached.

// Using an if statement, we can determine which button was pressed

// and change the appropriate values in our GUI.

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if(e.getSource() == redButton)

    {

        redScoreAmount = redScoreAmount + 1;

        redScore.setText(""+redScoreAmount);

    }

    else if(e.getSource() == blueButton)

    {

        blueScoreAmount = blueScoreAmount + 1;

        blueScore.setText(""+blueScoreAmount);

    }
else if(e.getSource() == greenButton)

    {

        greenScoreAmount = greenScoreAmount + 1;

        greenScore.setText(""+greenScoreAmount);

    }

    else if(e.getSource() == resetButton)

    {

        redScoreAmount = 0;

        blueScoreAmount = 0;
    greenScoreAmount = 0;

        redScore.setText(""+redScoreAmount);

        blueScore.setText(""+blueScoreAmount);
    greenScore.setText(""+greenScoreAmount);

    }

}



private static void createAndShowGUI() {



    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("[=] JButton Scores! [=]");



    //Create and set up the content pane.

    ButtonDemo_Extended3 demo = new ButtonDemo_Extended3();

    frame.setContentPane(demo.createContentPane());



    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.setSize(1024, 768);

    frame.setVisible(true);

}



public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:

    //creating and showing this application's GUI.

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            createAndShowGUI();

        }

    });

}

}
```

You have to use a layout manager in order to display your widgets. In this case I used a FlowLayout(). Also, make sure that you add the elements first in the panel and then you add the panel to its parent panel.

Now, the code works as you probably want, but again you should use a particular layout in order to arrange the panels inside the frame.

Answer (score 0):

If I run your code unmodified, I see just the "Red Team" label, and some buttons which are too small to read the text (and some of them only appear when moused over).

If you comment out all the null layouts:

```
    //buttonPanel.setLayout(null);
```

then all three buttons and labels appear properly.

Doing without a layout manager, and using absolute positioning, is possible (see the [Java Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html) page on this exact topic) but not usually recommended. There is a lot of information on using layout managers in the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) lesson of the Swing tutorials.